# Data in textfields not saving

Tags: ios, objective-c

this is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// for use in xib/storyboard:
#define TAG_TEXT_FIELD 10000
#define CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER @"EditableTextCell"

@interface EditableListViewController : UITableViewController

// list data:
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *contents;

// methods for possible overriding:
- (void)contentsDidChange;
- (UITextField *)createTextFieldForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell;

@end
```

and this is my .m file

```
#import "EditableListViewController.h"

static NSString *inactiveTextFieldHint = @"Tap to add item";
static NSString *activeTextFieldHint = @"";
static NSString *returnTappedTextFieldHint = @"~"; // HACK to mark when return was tapped

#pragma mark - Helper Categories

@interface UITextField (ChangeReturnKey)
- (void)changeReturnKey:(UIReturnKeyType)returnKeyType;
@end

@implementation UITextField (ChangeReturnKey)
- (void)changeReturnKey:(UIReturnKeyType)returnKeyType
{
    self.returnKeyType = returnKeyType;
    [self reloadInputViews];
}
@end

#pragma mark - EditableListViewController

@interface EditableListViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *rowsContent;
}
@end

@implementation EditableListViewController

#pragma mark - Contents Assignment

- (NSArray *)contents
{
    return rowsContent;
}

- (void)setContents:(NSArray *)contents
{
    rowsContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:contents];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark - Table Changes

- (void)deleteRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [rowsContent removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self contentsDidChange];
}

- (void)addRow:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath text:(NSString *)text
{
    if (rowsContent == nil) {
        rowsContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    }
    [rowsContent addObject:text];
    NSIndexPath *nextRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:indexPath.section];
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nextRow] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self contentsDidChange];
}

- (void)contentsDidChange
{
}

#pragma mark - Table View Data Source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return rowsContent.count + 1; // extra one for inserting new row
}

- (UITextField *)createTextFieldForCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    CGFloat padding = 8.0f;
    CGRect frame = CGRectInset(cell.contentView.bounds, padding, padding / 2);
    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    CGFloat spareHeight = cell.contentView.bounds.size.height - textField.font.pointSize;
    frame.origin.y = self.tableView.style == UITableViewStyleGrouped ? spareHeight / 2 : spareHeight - padding/2;
    textField.frame = frame;
    textField.tag = TAG_TEXT_FIELD;
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;
    textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    return textField;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseIdentifier = CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER;
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    }

    UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:TAG_TEXT_FIELD];
    if (textField == nil) {
        textField = [self createTextFieldForCell:cell];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
    }
    textField.delegate = self;
    if (indexPath.row < rowsContent.count) {
        textField.text = [rowsContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        textField.placeholder = nil;
    } else {
        textField.text = nil;
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(inactiveTextFieldHint, nil);
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (editingStyle) {

        case UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete: {
            [self deleteRow:indexPath];
            break;
        }

        case UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert: {
            UITableViewCell *sourceCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            UIView *textField = [sourceCell viewWithTag:TAG_TEXT_FIELD];
            [textField becomeFirstResponder];
            break;
        }

        case UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone:
            break;
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.section == 0);
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < rowsContent.count;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
    NSString *rowContent = [rowsContent objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [rowsContent removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [rowsContent insertObject:rowContent atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [self contentsDidChange];
}

#pragma mark - Table View Delegate

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section != 0) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return indexPath.row < rowsContent.count ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;
}

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath
    toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == 0 && proposedDestinationIndexPath.row < rowsContent.count
        ? proposedDestinationIndexPath
        : [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowsContent.count-1 inSection:0];
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (NSIndexPath *)cellIndexPathForField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UITableViewCell *parentCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:parentCell];
}

- (NSUInteger)rowIndexForField:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [self cellIndexPathForField:textField].row;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if ([textField.text length] == 0) {
        textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(activeTextFieldHint, nil);
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    textField.placeholder = returnTappedTextFieldHint;
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField.text.length == 0) {
        // if it's the last field, change the return key to "Next"
        if ([self rowIndexForField:textField] == rowsContent.count) {
            [textField changeReturnKey:UIReturnKeyNext];
        }
    }
    else {
        // if return button is "Next" and field is about to be empty, change to "Done"
        if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext && string.length == 0 && range.length == textField.text.length) {
            [textField changeReturnKey:UIReturnKeyDone];
        }
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField.returnKeyType == UIReturnKeyNext) {
        [textField changeReturnKey:UIReturnKeyDone];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *currRow = [self cellIndexPathForField:textField];
    NSUInteger cellIndex = currRow.row;
    if (cellIndex < rowsContent.count) {
        if ([textField.text length]) {
            if (![textField.text isEqualToString:[rowsContent objectAtIndex:cellIndex]]) {
                [rowsContent replaceObjectAtIndex:cellIndex withObject:textField.text];
                [self contentsDidChange];
            }
        }
        else {
            [self deleteRow:currRow];
        }
    }
    else { // new row
        if ([textField.text length]) {
            [self addRow:currRow text:textField.text];
            [textField changeReturnKey:UIReturnKeyDone];
            if ([textField.placeholder isEqual:returnTappedTextFieldHint]) { // if tapped return, go to the next field
                UITableViewCell *nextCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:cellIndex+1 inSection:currRow.section]];
                UIView *nextTextField = [nextCell viewWithTag:TAG_TEXT_FIELD];
                [nextTextField becomeFirstResponder];
            }
        }
        else {
            textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(inactiveTextFieldHint, nil);
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

When the User types in something, and leaves the app, exits the app in multitasking, the text that the user put in disappears and resets the text to like it was in the beginning.

What do I do, so that the text that the user puts in, it saves.

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: save the text in NSUserDefaults when user finish editing. And next run display the initialText taking from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: what code do i put in to use NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 0):

@user2102538 As asked by you, this is the way to use NSUserDefaults.

```
Saving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
 [prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
 [prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
 [prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
 [prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs.


 [prefs synchronize];///////Very Important. This SAVES THE NEWLY ADDED INTO NSUserDefaults


Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
 NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
 NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
 float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```

you can check whether NSUserDefault has object with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"yourKey"] // returns bool
```

or can even use like this

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yourKey"])
{
//no object present. Set the object.
}
else
{
//retrieve the object and do what u wish 
}
```